# && and || in Scala

Tags: scala, if-statement

since normal operators like +, ::, -> and so on are all methods which can be overloaded and stuff I was wondering if || and && are methods as well. This could theoretically work if this were methods in of the boolean object.
But if they are, why is something like

```
if (foo == bar && buz == fol)
```

possible? If the compiler reads from right to left this would invoke && on bar instead of (foo == bar)

Comment: `==` obviously has higher precedence than `&&`.

Comment: how is precedence defined then? is this only in the compiler or are there any rules on which operators are invoked first

Comment: The compiler determines that.

Comment: Now you should ask how a regular function && can have the same short-circuit evaluation semantics as && in other C-like languages.

Comment: That short-circuit evaluation is easy to do in Scala. Just pass the second parameter by name and evaluate it only if the first one evaluated to false.

Answer (score 30):

> 6.12.3 Infix Operations An infix operator can be an arbitrary
> identifier. Infix operators have
> precedence and associativity defined
> as follows:
>
> The precedence of an infix
> operator is determined by the
> operator’s first character. Characters
> are listed below in increasing order
> of precedence, with characters on the
> same line having the same precedence.

- (all letters)
- |
- ^
- &
- < >
- = !
- :
- + -
- * / %
- (all other special characters)

> That is, operators starting with a
> letter have lowest precedence,
> followed by operators starting with
> ‘|’, etc.
>
> There’s one exception to
> this rule, which concerns assignment
> operators(§6.12.4). The precedence of
> an assigment operator is the same as
> the one of simple assignment (=). That
> is, it is lower than the precedence of
> any other operator.

It follows with an explanation of associativity, and how it all combines in a expression with multiple operators. The [Scala Reference](http://www.scala-lang.org/sites/default/files/linuxsoft_archives/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf) makes good reading.

Answer (score 22):

Because [method starts with = has a higher precedence than method starts with &](http://programming-scala.labs.oreilly.com/ch03.html#_precedence_rules).

So (foo == bar && buz == fol) will become something like the following:

```
val tmp1: Boolean = (foo == bar)
val tmp2: Boolean = (buz  == fol)

tmp1 && tmp2
```

Answer (score 0):

Those two are definitely methods in scala.